# Has anybody figured out how to use pywin32 in a virtual environment?

Tags: pywin32

People have been trying for years to get pywin32 to work inside a virtual environment, and it seems nobody has succeeded yet.  At least, all the unanswered questions about how to do it are swamping the few questions that have received answers.  I need to have my Python script use COM to communicate with an ActiveX program, and so I need win32com.client.Dispatch(), and so I need pywin32.  I've read that pypiwin32 is the currently favored module, but it depends on pywin32.

I can load pywin32 into my registered copy of Python with no trouble, but I want to be able to use a virtual environment based on the 32-bit version of Python 3.8.

So how do I do it?  If I need a 64-bit version of Python, I can switch, but I'd rather not.

Here is what happens when I tried it using a venv based on 64-bit Python 3.8 on my Win10 box:

```
(venv) C:\misc\venv_test\venv\Scripts>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

(venv) C:\misc\venv_test\venv\Scripts>pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32

(venv) C:\misc\venv_test\venv\Scripts>pip install c:\misc\pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(venv) C:\misc\venv_test\venv\Scripts>pip install c:\misc\pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

And on a venv based on the 32-bit version of Python 3.8:

```
(venv) T:\Worthington Steel\Scripts Python3\venv\Scripts>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

(venv) T:\Worthington Steel\Scripts Python3\venv\Scripts>pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32

(venv) T:\Worthington Steel\Scripts Python3\venv\Scripts>pip install c:\misc\pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(venv) T:\Worthington Steel\Scripts Python3\venv\Scripts>pip install c:\misc\pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
pywin32-227-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(venv) T:\Worthington Steel\Scripts Python3\venv\Scripts>
```

Comment: Why not? It should work in a virtual environment.

Comment: I added copies of error messages from venvs based on both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your python file into an executable (must be 1 file, not a directory of files for your program). After that, move your executable that uses pywin32 into the virtual environment then run it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).